# Is there a way to grab either the min or max value from a string interval value in R?

Tags: r, string, max, min

I am given a vector x which contain these string price intervals

`x <- c("$100-$150","$90-$120","$30-$50")`

how would I write a function that would return a vector containing the min of each interval in numeric form?

`x <- c(100,90,30)`

In addition, how would I write a function that did the same thing but returned the max?

Comment: Using the `str_split()` function to split the strings into separate portions is one option as well to separate the start and end points.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `strcapture` from base R to get a `data.frame` with the min and max for the intervals:

```
strcapture("\\$([[:digit:]]+)-\\$([[:digit:]]+)", x, 
           data.frame(min = integer(), max = integer()))
##   min max
## 1 100 150
## 2  90 120
## 3  30  50
```

- The pattern (`"\\$([[:digit:]]+)-\\$([[:digit:]]+)"`) sets up the two capture groups of digits.
- `x` is the object we're reading from
- The proto form is being defined as a `data.frame` with two columns, named "min" and "max", each containing integer values.

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option using `regmatches` + `sapply`

```
> sapply(regmatches(x,gregexpr("\\d+",x)),function(x) min(as.numeric(x)))
[1] 100  90  30
```

---

If you want to have both `min` and `max` values, we can try

```
type.convert(
  setNames(
    data.frame(
      do.call(
        rbind,
        regmatches(x,gregexpr("\\d+",x)))),
    c("min","max")), 
  as.is = TRUE
  )
```

which gives

```
  min max
1 100 150
2  90 120
3  30  50
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `parse_number`

```
library(readr)
parse_number(x)
#[1] 100  90  30
```

---

Or with `sub` from `base R`

```
as.numeric(sub("\\$(\\d+)-.*", "\\1", x))
#[1] 100  90  30
```

Or to grab the max value

```
as.numeric(sub(".*-\\$(\\d+)", "\\1", x))
#[1] 150 120  50
```

---

Or this can be done using `read.table` from `base R` to create two column

```
read.table(text = gsub("$", "", x, fixed = TRUE), header = FALSE, sep="-")
#   V1  V2
#1 100 150
#2  90 120
#3  30  50
```

#### data

```
x <- c("$100-$150","$90-$120","$30-$50")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `stringr`, you can remove the $ and then split the string. The first row is the min, the second the max.

```r
library(stringr)

y <- sapply(str_split(str_remove_all(x, "[$]"), "-", 2), as.numeric)
y
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]  100   90   30
# [2,]  150  120   50

y_min <- y[1,]
y_max <- y[2,]
```

To break it down...

- `str_remove_all` is used to remove the '$' symbols
- `str_split` is used to split each element on the '-'
- `sapply` is used to convert each new character vector to numeric

---

If you want to go the `dplyr` route, you can `separate()`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

tibble(price = x) %>%
  mutate(price = str_remove_all(price, "[$]")) %>% 
  separate(price, c("min", "max"), sep = "-", convert = TRUE)

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#       min   max
#      <int> <int>
#   1   100   150
#   2    90   120
#   3    30    50
```